# Query optimization (OR based)

Tags: mysql

I have googled but I can't find answers for these questions.
Your advice is appreciated.

centOS on vps with 512MB RAM, nginx, php5 (fastcgi), mysql5 (myisam, not innodb).
I need to optimize this app created by some ex-employee. This app is working, but it's slow.

Table:

```
t1(id[bigint(20)],c1[mediumtext],c2[mediumtext],c3[mediumtext],c4[mediumtext])
id is some random big number, and is PK
```

Those mediumtext rows look like this:

```
c1="|box-002877|"
c2="|ct-2348|rd-11124854|hw-3949|wd-8872|hw-119037736|...etc.. "
c3="|fg-2448|wd-11172|hw-1656|...etc.. "
c4="|hg-2448|qd-16667|...etc."
    (some columns contain a lot of data, around 900 KiB, database around 300 MiB)
```

Yes, mediumtext "is bad", and (20) is too big... but I didn't create this.

Those codes can be found on any of those 4 mediumtext's...

```
//he needs all the columns of the row containing $code, so he wrote this:
function f1($code) {
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 LIKE '%$code%' OR c2 LIKE '%$code%' OR c3 LIKE '%$code%' OR c4 LIKE '%$code%';
```

Questions:

> Q1. If $code is found on c1... mysql
>   automatically stops checking and
>   returns row=id+c1+c2+c3+c4? or it will
>   continue (wasting time) checking c2,
>   c3 and c4?...
>
> Q2. Mysql is working with this table
>   on disk (not RAM) because of the
>   mediumtext, right? is this the primary cause of slowness?
>
> Q3. That query can be cached by mysql
>   (if using a big query_cache_size=128M
>   value on the my.cnf)? or that's not
>   cacheable due to the mediumtexts, or
>   due to the "OR LIKE"...?
>
> Q4. Do you recommend rewriting this with mysql's INSTR() / LOCATE() / MATCH..AGAINST [FULLTEXT]?

Comment: what language is that function f1 written in?  I assume some code was elided?  watch out for making a sql query by string concatenation or you may leave it open for attacks.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the WHERE to  '%$code%' LIKE c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: No, it will continue to search thru all the fields. If you use `Select top 1 * from ...`, that will stop from looking into the other fields.

Q2: That depends on your mySQL config, it is probably a cause of slowness but it is not probably the main cause.

Q3: An OR Like function will always be slow, and on big texts, it will be slower, you cannot do anything about it. I recommend you look for another way, and get rid of those LIKE statments, prefer a = sign.

Q4: No, it will make things slower.

Comment: on point 1, iirc MySQL doesn't use TOP, it uses LIMIT: Select * from .... LIMIT 0,1. Correct me if I'm wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> If $code is found on c1... mysql automatically stops checking and returns row=id+c1+c2+c3+c4? or it will continue (wasting time) checking c2, c3 and c4?...

Yes.

> Mysql is working with this table on disk (not RAM) because of the mediumtext, right? is this the primary cause of slowness?

No, `MEDIUMTEXT` is cached by the filesystem as well as the other datatypes. `MyISAM` does not support data page caching.

> That query can be cached by mysql (if using a big query_cache_size=128M value on the my.cnf)? or that's not cacheable due to the mediumtexts, or due to the "OR LIKE"...?

`MySQL` caches the queries verbatim. If you change anything in your query (including case of the statements and of course the values being searched for), this query will be treated as a cache miss and executed. `MEDIUMTEXT` queries are cached as well as the other queries.

> Do you recommend rewriting this with mysql's INSTR() / LOCATE() / MATCH..AGAINST [FULLTEXT]?

`FULLTEXT` indexing will certainly speed up the queries. Make sure, though, that the values you search for contain no word separators.

Answer (score 0):

For best results you should explode those text fields out into one or more tables and create some many-to-many joining tables in between.